# PDO code not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am new to PDO.. i tried out some online tutorials and found some step-by-step guides. i am using WAMP, i created a database named "try" with table named "books".
Now in my index.php i wrote:

```
<?php
$host   = "localhost:3306";
$db = "try";
$user   = "clyde";
$pass   = "moonfang";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
$q   = $conn->query($sql) or die("failed!");    

while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){    
    echo $r['title'];
} 
?>
```

Now whenever i load localhost on my browser i see these errors;
[image]
i dont understand the problem.. :-(

Comment: Check all values .. $host (is it localhost is it 3307 port), $db, $user, $pass

Comment: Do you actually have a MySQL server running on the same machine as your webserver, and listening on TCP port 3307? The default MySQL port is 3306, not 3307.

Comment: yes the local host and port is right. when i use mysql it works but with the PDO codes it does not..:-(

Answer (score 2):

According to [several examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php#89019) it seems that PDO prefers the `host` and the `port` in the dsn for itself:

```
$host = "localhost";
$port = 3307;
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
```

[Here's the PHP manual for the PDO MySQL DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php). Note the "port" part.

Comment: +1 Nice catch. I faintly remember this being a possible issue.

Comment: @ClydeWinux Is your MySQL server running? What if you telnet to localhost on this port? (If you're running Windows 7 and don't have telnet installed, [follow this manual](http://www.fettesps.com/windows-7-enable-telnet/) or use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/))

Comment: i tried this but i got the same error. when i use mysql codes to connect to the database it works, but with PDO it does not. do i need to change some setting on my WAMP server?

Comment: @ClydeWinux Could you edit the OP with the exact mysql codes that you used, where it worked?

Comment: i tried telnet already. it says it can't connect to localhost port 3307. here's the mysql codes that worked:
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
    mysql_select_db("try");

Comment: Where exactly does this specify the port as being 3307? If it's not specified then it defaults to 3306.

Comment: i already changed it to 3306. now i get new error, it says access denied for user "clyde" with password. its the correct username and password in mysql..

Comment: @ClydeWinux As I previously requested, can you post the *exact* `mysql` code that worked in your OP (original post) as an **edit** and in **code tags**?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *the target machine actively refused [the connection]*.

Therefore you have to check if usernames/passwords/access-rights to the database server are all OK; including IP/host and port/firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

Line 8 where error occurs is  `$q   = $conn->query($sql) or die("failed!");` This line  mixes mysql_ and PDO and is not required.

The code should look like

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books";
while($r = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){    
   echo $r['title'];
}
```

You should also incorporate PDO error handling

`